# how to call a method and make it run in background in python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-messaging, python-asyncio

I have implemented the Google Cloud Messaging server in python and I want that method to be Asynchronous. I do not expect any return values from that method. Is there a simple way to do this?
I have tried using `async` from `asyncio` package:

```
...
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 if(module_status=="Fail"):
      loop.run_until_complete(sendNotification(module_name, module_status))
...
```

and here is my method `sendNotification()`:

```
async def sendNotification(module_name, module_status):
    gcm = GCM("API_Key")
    data ={"message":module_status, "moduleName":module_name}
    reg_ids = ["device_tokens"]
    response = gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data)
    print("GCM notification sent!")
```

Comment: If the `gcm.json_request` method is not defined using `asyncio`, then there is not a simple way to do this.

Comment: @NateMara I am using python-gcm librabry  [link](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm/blob/master/gcm/gcm.py). I saw its code and it is not async. Can you suggest a solution to make my method run in background?

Comment: You could use `multiprocessing` or do the HTTP call yourself using `aiohttp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def send_notification(module_name, module_status):
    [...]

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future = executor.submit(send_notification, module_name, module_status)
```

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Could you elaborate?

Comment: Indeed my comment was lacking details, apologies. My code is still executing properly but I was expecting it to run in background and immediately show some prints I've done after the `with` block. I guess I'm doing it wrong. Let me try again.

Comment: It seems I'm progressing. Now I have the error message `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'migrate' was never awaited`.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland The `with` statement uses the executor as a context manager in order to make sure all the the submitted jobs have terminated before continuing with the program.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, if this answer is for synchronous execution, I'm not sure to understand why it is marked as the correct answer. Isn't the question about executing an *asynchronous* process in background?

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Sorry I wasn't so clear. Original poster said he wanted to run a job in the background, and that he tried to use asyncio. But it seems like his library, gcm, does not support asyncio (meaning, it does not provide coroutines to use in the context of an asyncio application). So the easiest solution to his problem is probably to use a threadpool executor in order to submit (synchronous) jobs to a background thread and get the results later. This also means that with this solution, `send_notification` is no longer a coroutine (`async def`) but a regular function (`def`).

Answer (score 2):

Since GCM is not async library compatible need to use an external event loop.

There are a few, simplest one IMO is probably [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/).

Note that gevent monkey patching may introduce dead locks if the underlying libraries used rely on blocking behaviour to operate.

```
import gevent
from gevent.greenlet import Greenlet
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

def sendNotification(module_name, module_status):
    gcm = GCM("API_Key")
    data ={"message":module_status, "moduleName":module_name}
    reg_ids = ["device_tokens"]
    response = gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids, data=data)
    print("GCM notification sent!")

greenlet = Greenlet.spawn(sendNotification, 
                          args=(module_name, module_status,))
# Yield control to gevent's event loop without blocking
# to allow background tasks to run
gevent.sleep(0)
# 
# Other code, other greenlets etc here
# 
# Call get to get return value if needed
greenlet.get()
```

Comment: why do you need `monkey.patch_all()` ?

Comment: `GCM is not async library compatible`

Answer (score 1):

You can use asyncio's api: `loop.run_in_executor(None, callable)`

This will run the code using an executor (by default a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor))

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor)